Preload page in nuxt/vue
I'm trying to implement a little preloader for a site built in vue/nuxt2.
I want the proloader to display when the user go to the start page or any other page but i dont want it to display when navigate inside the app between pages using the menu (since stuff then already is loaded).
Is the correct way to then put it in my app.vue file?
The code itself works, i just want to know where the correct way is to put it to achieve the behaviour explained.
<script>
  import { gsap, Expo } from 'gsap'

  export default {
    mounted() {
      document.readyState === 'complete' ? this.load() : 
      window.addEventListener('load', this.load)
    },
    methods: {
      load() {
          //code to animate a loader later on.
      }
    }
  }
</script>


There is already a preloader in Nuxt2 that you could use and maybe check the source code of: https://v2.nuxt.com/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-render#shouldpreload--shouldprefetch Otherwise look on Github.
